# Nodejs-How to get user details in login function

Tags: node.js

this is my user.js

```
/ Route for user logins
router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).select('email password active').exec(function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err; // Throw err if cannot connect

    // Check if user is found in the database (based on username)           
    if (!user) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Username not found' }); // Username not found in database
    } else if (user) {
      // Check if user does exist, then compare password provided by user
      if (!req.body.password) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'No password provided' }); // Password was not provided
      } else {
        var validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password); // Check if password matches password provided by user 
        if (!validPassword) {
          res.json({ success: false, message: 'Could not authenticate password' }); // Password does not match password in database
        } else if (!user.active) {
          res.json({ success: false, message: 'Account is not yet activated. Please check your e-mail for activation link.', expired: true }); // Account is not activated 
        } else {
          //var token = jwt.sign({ email: user.email}, config.secret, { expiresIn: '24h' }); // Logged in: Give user token
          const token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), config.secret, {expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
        });
          res.json({ success: true, message: 'User authenticated!', token: 'JWT '+token,
          user: {
            id: user._id,
            firstname: user.firstname,
            lastname: user.lastname,
            email: user.email
          }
        }); // Return token in JSON object to controller
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

this /authenticate is working properly, but i can't get user firstname and lastname.i get email ,id detail only, i don't know where i did mistake please help me.

Comment: i don't know , how to get user detail from model.

Comment: You have to explicitly pass the column names you want to retrieve in `.select` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are retrieving the User from the database in this line

`User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).select('email password active').exec(function(err, user) {`

you are choosing to select only the email password and active properties.
If you want the firstname and lastname, you will need to change it to

`User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).select('email password active firstname lastname').exec(function(err, user) {`

Edit: More information

Documentation page for the .select() method
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select

States about .select():

`Specifies which document fields to include or exclude (also known as the query "projection")`